# How can I dynamically get the 'title' value of a route when it changes while navigating?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

### Context and problem

I've defined a few routes inside an `app-routing.module` as follows:

```
// imports

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', title: 'Home Route', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'other', title: 'Other Route', component: OtherComponent},
  { path: 'another', title: 'Yet Another Route', component: YetAnotherComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And I've also defined a `navigation-title.component` which I want to use to display the current route as `"My App | Home Route"` or `"My App | Other Route"`, for example.

However, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to bind to the route title.

### Things I've tried

#### Injecting `ActivatedRoute` into my `navigation-title` component

I first tried injecting a `private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute` and binding to `this.activatedRoute.title` (which is an `Observable<string | undefined>`) with an `async` pipe, but this activated route doesn't actually seem to change while you navigate about.

#### Hooking to router navigation events

Next, I tried subscribing to the router events, specifically to `NavigationEnd`, in order to update the title, but retrieving the title from the activated route when the navigation ended always resulted in getting the title of the previous route.

#### Binding to the router outlet

Finally, I bound to the `router-outlet`'s `(activate)` event with an event handler inside my `navigation-title.component` using some code behind (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JansthcirlU/73830d5c1042a397b60f59d2c07f01d4) for more details), but unfortunately this results in a tight coupling between my title component and the router outlet.

Isn't there a better (i.e. fully decoupled) way to simply get the route title from an injected `Router` or `ActivatedRoute` somehow?

### P.S.

I certainly **DO NOT** want to work with the `TitleService` because it makes no sense to let a component set the page title when you can already define it inside the route that yields said component.

Comment: if the titles are not dynamic, why not just add "My App |" to the property?

Comment: @CaioOliveira because I would have to change more things if I decide to change my app name

Comment: posted your answer, I think it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If the title it not dynamic but you still want to do something different, you could use the tittle strategy from angular 14 +

Source: https://dev.to/brandontroberts/setting-page-titles-natively-with-the-angular-router-393j

```
@Injectable()
export class TemplatePageTitleStrategy extends TitleStrategy {
  constructor(private readonly title: Title) {
    super();
  }

  override updateTitle(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const title = this.buildTitle(routerState);
    if (title !== undefined) {
      this.title.setTitle(`My App | ${title}`);
    }
  }
}
```

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: TitleStrategy,
      useClass: TemplatePageTitleStrategy
    }
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this sets the entire page title to `My App | Some Title`, right? I'm actually looking for a way to keep the `Some Title` as the page title, but to use that `Some Title` value inside a component that displays `My App | Some Title`.

Comment: It will get the title from the route, and just prefix it with My App |

Comment: you could resort to Resolvers to handle different data. What I am understanding is that you need a separation from the actual title on the tab, with the page 'name'. Or you could just add a data attribute to your route

Comment: Correct, I'd like to distinguish the route title (shown on the tab, regardless of the strategy) from the displayed title inside my component. I did not know about using the data attribute, that could be an interesting avenue, though I still find it very strange that there's no sane and simple way to get the title from the activated route somehow...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem for quite a while and still couldn't resolve in a way that satisfy me, however a working workaround is to inject the `Router` and `Title`in your component and then subscribe to the events of `NavigationEnd`.

If you try to get the title through the `getTitle()` right after the event is fired you'll get the wrong title (previous' page), if you set a timeout it gets the right one.

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private titleService: Title) {
    this.router.events.subscribe({
      next: (event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            const title = this.titleService.getTitle();
            console.log('Title: ', title);
          }, 50); //TODO: If no timeout it gets previous page title
        }
      },
    });
  }
```